# Spotfire Join in Information Designer is not Working

Tags: spotfire

I am new to Spotfire and I am trying to join two information link data  ( user List and Sales of the user ). But when I joined using the data source > data tab > create join  ( source field match ) %1 AND %2 . But  the result is not showing the matching records but instead it shows all records,"""

Can you help me understand how to join in Spotfire .

what i am trying to do is to do a personalize information link and implement the row level sceurty using fuction ( CURRENT_USER () ).

Please let me know the same DXP or working copy or step for my learning reference.

We  would need your help on learning this . as i am new.

Comment: This forum is more for code problems and you are asking for some training direction which is not the purpose of this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `%CURRENT_USER%` in the `Filter` section of the Source Columns.

```
I.e. %1 = %CURRENT_USER%
```

Anything beyond this and we'd need to see your sample data. Note, you could also do the joins at the datasource, and limit the final result set this way.